# Fusionchart zoomchart show certain section programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, fusioncharts

I am using a 'zoomline' Chart from the fusioncharts framework.

I am displaying some values which change over time. Now I want to implement a function to directly address one month or any other timespan with something like this:

```
new FusionCharts({
            "type": "zoomline",
            "id": "example",
            "renderAt": "chartContainer",
            "dataSource": {
                "chart": {
                    {
                        "xAxisZoomBegin": "2018-03-01"
                    },
                    {
                        "xAxisZoomEnd": "2018-04-01"
                    }
                },
                ...
            },
            ...
        });
```

Whereas `xAxisZoomBegin` and `xAxisZoomEnd` don't really exist but I'm looking for something like that but haven't found anything in their documentation. Do you have any advice how I can do this?

Comment: Found the solution! It's the zoomTo callback: https://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/594wd3uu/

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts supports methods like zoomOut, zoomTo, and resetChart which will help you to achieve your requirement.
Check out this [doc](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods#zoomout-78) to know more about these methods.

Samples are given in the doc itself, you can refer them for your implementation.